# Stripe checkout button on dynamic/Ajax page

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I've integrated the Stripe checkout button with script tag inside a form, according to [the standard example](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout). It works if the content is output as a new HTML page, but if the content is introduced dynamically (via Ajax and innerHTML), the button isn't shown. How can I trigger it manually?

Comment: 4k reputation? Presumably you've read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask?

Comment: I was avoiding any code because there's a standard example. I've linked to it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways I can think of, the first, and I'd say the best way, is don't use the Standard Example, but instead use Stripe's [Custom Example](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom). Then you can just call `handler.open({...})`.

Or, if you must use the inline script, I forced the button's click event using jQuery.

```
$(".stripe-button-el").click();
```

But I don't recommend this because not all browsers are going to support it for security reasons.